# Multiple if and if not in list comprehension

Tags: list, python-3.x, if-statement

I tried to look at similar questions but I'm really not understanding how I can accomplish this using the methods mentioned in the other questions.
So my problem is: I have one list from which I want to remove certain values. For instance:

```
a = [[[0,0],[0,1]],[[0,0],[0,1]]]
for y in range(2):
    a[y][:] = [x for x in a[y] if not random.random() < s]
```

This removes the elements for which random.random() is below s (being s between 0 and 1). However, I only want this to happen if the second position of each element of the list (that is the [0,0] bit) is equal to 1. I tried multiple solutions (suggested around here for other questions) and I can't get it to work. Does anyone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another condition could be added to check the value of the second "bit" of `x` (`x[1] == 0`):

```
a = [[[0,0],[0,1]],[[0,0],[0,1]]]
for y in range(2):
    a[y][:] = [x for x in a[y] if x[1] == 0 or random.random() >= 0.5]
```

This means that if `x[1] == 0`, then the pair is kept, regardless of a random value. Otherwise, it is kept only if `random.random() >= 0.5`.